# How to use Powershell Invoke-Item with a gci search?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to build a Powershell script that uses the Invoke-Item cmdlet once I've found the files using the following script:

```
gci -Recurse -File *.xls* C:\folder_example\'  |  sort LastWriteTime | Select -last 2 |
```

I'm not sure how best to implement the  Invoke-Item cmdlet from here?

Comment: You just add it to the end, what do you mean? 
`gci -Recurse -File .xls C:\folder_example'  |   sort LastWriteTime | Select -last 2 | Invoke-Item`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its simplest usage, `Invoke-Item` (aliased as `ii`) just needs a path given to it either through pipeline or through a parameter.

In this case, it could be as simple as adding `| Invoke-Item` to the end of your command:

```
gci -Recurse -File *.xls* C:\folder_example\ | sort LastWriteTime | select -Last 2 | Invoke-Item
```

One thing I will mention, is that I have found that certain programs cannot handle a bunch of files thrown at them in quick succession like this script will do.

I usually run into this when trying to open a bunch of files in Notepad++.

I'm going to simplify the command a bit just to keep it short...but usually one of these two changes will fix my problem:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xls* | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Item $_.FullName }
```

Placing the call into a `ForEach-Object` script block will sometimes fix this. I'm not 100% why this fixes it, I have some theories but that's all they are, so I will keep them out of this answer. But it always fixes the issue for me when using `Invoke-Item` on Notepad++ files.

Some programs, like Excel, have a start up splash screen and some lag before they eventually open. So you could always throw a sleep in there just to help slow things down a bit in case you are still having trouble:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xls* | ForEach-Object { Start-Sleep 0.1; Invoke-Item $_.FullName }
```

That will add a small 100ms pause just to give whatever application you are running to have a little time to process.

Comment: Chad this was a big help for this a two other scripts I've been working on thanks!!!

Comment: @MattGilbert Awesome! If you feel this answered your question, please be sure to mark it as the answer 